# How to load memory at 51.2GB/s on quad-channel memory architecture?

Tags: memory, hardware, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

This is actually a coding problem.

I have a i7-3820 with 4 * 4GB DDR3 1600Mhz computer running under linux. According to Intel's spec, I believe that I can scan memory at the 51.2GB/s (not GiB/s). But unfortunately I only get 40GB/s.

First of all I coded a memory to xmm loading procedure in assembly. Suppose it's declared as

```c
extern "C" {
    void load_mem_256b(int *start, int *end, int step, int *p_sum);
}
```

The return value is the sum of the first int of all loaded integers to avoid optimization.

It will load 256bits from the memory address pointed by start, then advance start by step * 8 (8 * sizeof(int) = 256 bits)

I've tried two ways to read the memory, the first way is to open 4 threads, divide the memory into 4 segments; the other way is to open 4 threads, let each thread load the i-th 256b part in 1024b, and sync the 4 threads properly.

The first method achieved 40GB/s as I mentioned before. The second method is slower.

In the first method, if the memory is working in ganged mode, there will be a lot of access of memory in the different row. Since I have 2 ranks per DIMM * 4 DIMMs, I don't know if it would work fine without performance degrading. In the second method, I suppose to let the memory loads happen to only the same row, and let different thread load from different memory channel.

The first method look like this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(
        load_mem_256b, start + i * 8, end, number_of_threads, &(sums[i])));
```

The second method look like this:

```c
size_t amount = 32768;
my::spin_barrier barrier(number_of_threads + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(load_mem_256b_barrier,
                       start + i * 8, end,
                       number_of_threads,
                       &barrier, amount, &(sums[i])));
threads[number_of_threads] = std::thread(std::bind(
    prefetch, start, end, amount, &barrier));
```

A few additional data is, in the first method, if I only open 1 or 2 or 3 threads, I can load the memory at 17GB/s, 32GB/s, 39GB/s. I feel strange with all these numbers. If the memory is working at unganged mode, why 1 thread can load the memory at 17GB/s? (A single channel can only send 12.8GB/s) But if it's working at ganged mode, why the second method significantly slower than the first method?

And finally, how to actually load memory at the theoretical speed?

Comment: From a few sources (like http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/393131) I found that the memory address is mapped to: row, rank, bank, high col, channel, low col (3 bits) . Typical 16GB memory has 16bits row, 1bits rank, 3bits bank, 11bits col.

Comment: CL11, 2^10 col, DDR3, 4 channel has 12800 * 128 / (33 + 128) * 4 throughput for sequential read. If I could pre-active the next row for some (rank, bank) then the tRAS + tCL + tRP part can be eliminated.